# Signed distance field font atlas - size reduction of the texture

Tags: opengl, fonts, texture-atlas

I have an SDF atlas (8bit grayscale) with all the Arial glyphs, which is about 16k^2 pixels. Rendering text works more or less fine, but such texture eats about 256MB of GPU memory. Graphics system is OpenGL.

Q: Are there any solutions as to not having to use such large texture while maintaining the ability to render any character from the Arial font?

I am using my own  implementation of standalone SDF generator which actually first renders all the glyphs using WPF and then calculates the SDF using CUDA (naive implementation, per pixel brute-force, takes about 20 minutes to calculate, I do not have the skill to optimize it), but because of that WPF stuff, that approach is a no go for on-the-fly atlas generation for individual strings (speed, D3D9). Generating even a small SDF on the fly on the GPU would also not be stunningly fast and might introduce lags in rendering.

I just want to avoid using any libs like FreeType and at the same time do not want to end up implementing the whole TTF standard - after all it is just a hobby project, ít is not in my capacity.

I was thinking about something like keeping an MRU atlas and update it accordingly every time I render a string, but that would require a lot of housekeeping code - mapping from the main atlas, on-the-fly packing, tracking MRU glyphs coordinates in the atlas and last but not least might cause even bigger slowdowns when rendering larger or many strings with lots of different characters.

Comment: "*which is about 16k^2 pixels ... eats about 2 gigs*" How'd that happen? 16kx16k is 256MPixels, which should take up 256MB in storage. How did you get an image 8 times that in size?

Comment: It just happened so that I made a huge mistake in the question. Of course you are right, the texture is 256M pixels, but the overall size of ALL of my font atlases is 2GB. I have edited the question to make it correct. The rest still of the question still applies.